# Run groovy uncompiled script with single jar file on java jre

Tags: java, groovy

I would like to execute uncompiled groovy scripts with the java jre. I would like to provide just one jar file to do this. I think in older groovy versions this was possible with a groovy-all jar.

e.g. `java -cp lib/groovy-all-2.4.6.jar;. groovy.ui.Main myscript.groovy`

But this groovy all jar does not exist for new groovy versions. Is there another jar to do that?

Comment: Take a look at this thread: http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/What-is-the-best-replacement-for-running-scripts-using-groovy-all-td5755661.html

Comment: depends on what features of groovy you are using.. it's possible that you just need `groovy-2.4.6.jar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the [gradle-groovy-all](https://github.com/gradle/gradle-groovy-all) project in this [thread](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/What-is-the-best-replacement-for-running-scripts-using-groovy-all-td5755661.html). This works fine for me. With the newest commit on the master branch the dependency `org.apache.ivy` is incuded in the built jar.

Answer (score 1):

There are many `groovy-$something` artifacts (`sql`, `json`, ...) and
`all` was just the combined jar with all of them in it in the 2.4 days.

Now the "-all" is only deployed as Bill Of Materials, that itself no longer
is/contains a jar, but points to all other groovy-$something artifacts itself as transitive deps.

So using "groovy.jar" and "groovy-(a|b|c).jar" might be a way out for you and this all boils down to one jar, if you don't need anything else but `groovy.jar`.

Or you could roll your own "all" jar (e.g. build a uber-/fat/shadow-jar
in a project with all deps you need (e.g. `groovy-all` and whatnot).

Comment: Tank you =) I hoped that there is already a jar which I can use. I found the project https://github.com/gradle/gradle-groovy-all in a comment of my question. Sadly the dependency apache ivy isn't included in the built jar. So the @Grap annotation doesn't work. I am checking to add this dependency to the project but I am not very deep into gradle. But if there is no existing groovy-all jar I want to build my own